# Android crash ClassCastException but no project lines

Tags: android, classcastexception

My Application is crashing on an GT-P5110 Android 4.2.2 Samsung Tab 2 tablet. I'm currently searching all my code but can't find where it is called. I got the error output right here.

I can't find a listview which is casting this problem. I even disabled whole parts. Anyone got an idea?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
   at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1872)
   at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1841)
   at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:681)
   at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:742)
   at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1645)
   at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2511)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14694)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4491)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1021)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14694)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4491)
   at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:931)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14694)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4491)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14694)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4491)
   at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:493)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14694)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4491)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14694)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4491)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1669)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1527)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14694)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4491)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14694)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4491)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2200)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2014)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1227)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4995)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: Can you please post your code too?

Comment: Debug it. Somewhere you are using wrong `LayoutParams` (should be `android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams` but you are using `android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams`).

Comment: Post my code? It's an Android project 10MB big. I have no clue where it's crashing. If it was I would have posted any relevant code. Any clue where I should be searching for?

Comment: Can you add the xml, code of the list view, adapter relate to your drawerLayout?

Comment: There is no XML for my DrawerLayout :) Im using 

new DrawerBuilder().withActivity(this).withTranslucentStatusBar(false).build(); from the com.mikepenz.materialdrawer

Comment: Can you reveal the code of your DrawerItem? I think issue can be in the `convertView` of `DrawerItem`

Comment: Turns out the MaterialDrawer Library I used had a problem realy realy deep and somehow crashed when used within a Fragment. I have build a solution arround it and it seems to be working atm. Thanks alot :)